# How to do many-to-one mapping in a Hibernate hbm file

Tags: java, hibernate, hbmxml

I need to use many to one relationship between two tables while using the spring hibernate integrated program. I have `employee.hbm.xml` and `admin.hbm.xml` which has corresponding bean classes.

`empid`  in  `employee.hbm.xml`  acts as a foreign key in `admin.hbm.xml` .

**employee.hbm.xml**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="entity.Employee" table="employee">
<id name="empid" column="empid" type="java.lang.Integer">
<generator class="native"></generator>

</id>
<property name="empname" column="empname" type="java.lang.String"></property>
<property name="password" column="password" type="java.lang.String"></property>
<property name="designation" column="designation" type="java.lang.String"></property>
<property name="domain" column="domain" type="java.lang.String"></property>
<property name="role" column="role" type="java.lang.String"></property>
<property name="head" column="head" type="java.lang.String"></property>
<property name="specialist" column="specialist" type="java.lang.String"></property>

</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**admin.hbm.xml**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="entity.Admin" table="admin">
<id name="courseid" column="courseid" type="java.lang.Integer">
<generator class="increment"></generator>
</id>
<property name="coursename" column="coursename" type="java.lang.String"></property>
<property name="participants" column="participants" type="java.lang.Integer"></property>
<!-- <property name="empid" column="empid" type="java.lang.Integer"/> -->
<many-to-one name="employee" class="entity.Employee" fetch="select" 
column="empid" cascade="all"/>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

while i try to insert to admin table, i get a `NullPointerException` on field `empid`. what should i modify to make foreign key constraint between these two `hbm` files???

Comment: Did you check http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_one_to_many_mapping.htm

Comment: That doesn't help in my coding.. i need to know where should i make change to map between the hbm files.Thankyou

Comment: In this link they mentioned one `Emp` have more than one `certificates`. So `Emp` have `1ToManey Relationship`.Now you have to decide what mapping you are doing.

Comment: ok joshi thanks its many to one but actually problem is i am getting null pointer exception i'm not able to get the value setted in employee class object in admin class

Comment: can you post your error trace so that we can understand what is the real problem?

Comment: root cause of the error is:org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update; SQL [insert into admin (coursename, participants, empid, courseid) values (?, ?, ?, ?)]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update